# AngularJS - How to set the value of the checkbox as true by checking another checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have two checkboxes. If you click checkbox B, checkbox A must be checked too. But in my code, when I click checkbox B, the checkbox A is also checked. But the ng-model of checkbox A is not changing it's value from false to true. Can someone help me with this? Thank you in advance! Here's my code below: (Try running the code snippet)

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Box a
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="box2" ng-model="box1">{{box1}}<br />
    Box b
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="box2"> {{box2}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.box1 = false;
            $scope.box2 = false;
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Commercial Suicide has a good answer. I also found another method which uses less logic. Check the codes below:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Box a
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="box2" ng-model="box1">{{box1}}<br />
    Box b
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="click()" ng-model="box2"> {{box2}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.box1 = false;
            $scope.box2 = false;
            
            $scope.click = function () {
                $scope.box1 = $scope.box2;
            };
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be attach a `change` event handler to the second `checkbox` and change the `box1's` scope inside this method.

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Box a
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="box2" ng-model="box1">{{box1}}<br />
    Box b
    <input type="checkbox"  ng-change="change()" ng-model="box2"> {{box2}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
              app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.box1 = false;
            $scope.box2 = false;
            $scope.change=function(){
               $scope.box1=$scope.box2;
            }
            });
    </script>
```

One single advice:

`ng-model` and `ng-checked` are not **meant** to be used **together**.

`ng-checked` is expecting an expression, so by saying `ng-checked="true"`, you're basically saying that the checkbox will always be checked.

You should be able to just use `ng-model`, binded to a `boolean` property on your model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @alexandru-lonut Mihai. I also found a similar method like this.

Comment: @JPDolocanog, ng-checked does not change the ng-model..so, you must to do this manually.

Comment: @Alexandru-lonutMihai noted. Thank you for that informative advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ng-change` directive on box2, which will invoke the function, where you can change the value of box1 programmatically, like this:

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Box a
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="box2" ng-model="box1">{{box1}}<br />
    Box b
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="box2" ng-change="checkBox1()"> {{box2}}
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.box1 = false;
    $scope.box2 = false;
    $scope.checkBox1 = function() {
      $scope.box1 = $scope.box2;
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Commercial Suicide. I posted my answer before your edit. But still a good answer though.

Comment: @JPDolocanog, Thank you, nice to hear, that it helps

Answer (score 0):

Pass same variable into ng-model of both input boxes

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Box a
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="box2" ng-model="box1">{{box1}}<br />
    Box b
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="box2" ng-change="onChange()"> {{box2}}
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.box1 = false;
            $scope.box2 = false;
            $scope.onChange= function(){
              $scope.box1= $scope.box2;    
            }; 
            });
           
    </script>
```

Comment: Good point, but checkbox A needs to have an independent variable since it can be checked without the help of checkbox B. Only checkbox B is dependent to checkbox A.

Answer (score 0):

basically, ng-checked does not change the value of `$scope.box1`.
what you can do is display `{{box2 || box1}}` instead of `{{box1}}`

Comment: That's what I realized right now. I have been fooled by this issue. I really need the ng-models to be updated since I am storing these values to my database.